# How to Add/Subtract time in DevC++

Tags: c++, time

```
time (&rawtime); timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime); strftime (buffer,80,"%I:%M:%S",timeinfo);
```

This is my code to get time. Just count buffer and it works perfectly fine.
I have 2 times `(Time Started and Time Finished)` and I want to get its process time. Basically its `Time2-Time1 formula` but I don't know how to do it with this current format. Thanks!!

Comment: `<chrono>` has a considerably simpler interface.

Comment: `<chrono>` video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a `struct tm`, the first thing you'll want to do is convert it into a time_t via [mktime()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime).  time_t is more useful for subtraction since it is a simple integer, representing seconds-since-the-epoch-began.  Once you have two time_t values, you can simply subtract one from the other, and the result will the number of seconds between the two times.